# Deploy node.js on local server

Tags: node.js

I am currently running a website written with Flask on a LAMP server.  I used mod_wsgi to connect the Flask app with Apache, and all is running well.  However, I recently discovered websockets and would like to use them in my website.  There is a Flask extension for websockets, but I was told Apache does not support websockets and that I could not use it.

I was introduced to Socket.IO running on nodejs at school, and I would like to try it out for my website (rewrite my website using nodejs).  My question is how do I run the nodejs app from my local server as I did with my Flask app?  I have searched Google, and people are recommending using Apache or Nginx, but will they support websockets?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By launching your nodeJS server... Take a look at : [A simple TCP based chat server written in node.js](https://gist.github.com/creationix/707146)

(I'm not the author and I don't know him)

Then just: `node myFile.js`